# Android Collapsing Toolbar like Android Settings App

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm trying to to create a collapsing toolbar like Android Settings App.

What I want:(Settings->Display, this is a Samsung Galaxy J5 2017 with Android 9)

https://github.com/danut-betuel/CollapsingToolbarDemo/blob/master/android_collapsing_toolbar.gif

What I did:

https://github.com/danut-betuel/CollapsingToolbarDemo/blob/master/collapsing_toolbar.gif

These are not 100% identical.

Are there other simpler ways to achieve this?

I made a Demo project for this.(https://github.com/danut-betuel/CollapsingToolbarDemo)

Answer (score 0):

I think CollapsingToolbar is too complex view and it's really hard to do something custom with it. Simplest way to make animation like this is MotionLayout. With MotionLayout you can customise animation durations with keyframes (https://medium.com/google-developers/defining-motion-paths-in-motionlayout-6095b874d37)
Unfortunately, MotionLayout in beta right now. But, anyway, I suggest to try it.

More examples with collapsing behaviour with MotionLayout:
https://blog.stylingandroid.com/motionlayout-collapsing-toolbar-part-1/
https://medium.com/google-developers/introduction-to-motionlayout-part-iii-47cd64d51a5